# Why does a repeated quantifier in vim match *fewer* than the specified copies?

Tags: regex, vim

So, I have a search like this: `\v(\_\s{-1,}[^ ]+){24}\.` (It's a part of a much larger regex, but it should basically match the first twenty-four words *before* a period.)

```
antihistamines, antiepileptics, and narcotics (Winkler, Auer, Doering, & Rief, 2014); and beyond the
laundry-list of such pharmaceuticals, there's several non-pharmacological treatments for sleep
disorder, including everything from the cognitive-behavioural therapies I'll be discussing below to
acupuncture.

WHY DOES *THIS* SENTENCE MATCH.
```

[image]

The last sentence gets matched, and it's *definitely* not 24 words long. What am I doing wrong, here?

For reference, the overall regex being constructed looks something like this:

```
\v(%^|\.)@<=(\_[^[:alnum:]]{-1,}[^ ]+){-1,} ...
    ((\_\s{-1,}([^ ]+)\_\s*(\(\_[^\)]*\d{4}\))?){24}\_\s*\.)@=
```

> I really wish there was something like [Regexr](http://regexr.com) or [Rubular](http://rubular.com) for Vim regexen … they're so strange, and it's really hard to get a handle on *precisely* what the engine is doing with any given clause. Also, I thoroughly and deeply wish Vim-regexen supported something like `(?#comments)`. `-_-`

Comment: In Vim wouldn't you need to use a backslash in front of certain [quantifiers](http://vimregex.com/#Non-Greedy) `\{n}`,  `\+`, ...

Comment: Even in `\v` `'verymagic'` mode?

Comment: what is `\s{-1,}` ? [`((?:[\w\W]){24})\.`](https://regex101.com/r/rV7yR1/1) ?

Comment: This doesn't really help you with your problem directly, but as a general piece of advice I would say that if your regexes are starting to get bigger than the screen width, I feel that perhaps it's time to break the problem up in smaller pieces (which may simply be smaller regexes)...

Comment: Oh, @Carpetsmoker, there's a half-dozen better ways to do this (as is usually true of any almost solution involving regexen `:P`); it started out as an ill-advised yak-shaving … but nonetheless, it *should* work, as far as I can tell. `/=`

Comment: @Thomas should match a minimum of one (`{1,}`) spaces (`\s`), non-greedily (`{-   }`).

Comment: @ELLIOTTCABLE: `[^ ]` matches a dot.  Add it if you want to avoid matching "words" containing a period: `\v(\_\s{-1,}[^. ]+){24}\.`

Comment: @ELLIOTTCABLE isn't this the same as `+` ?

Comment: I can't reproduce. When I run the regex the why does this match line isn't matched.